# filesending for index.html overrides all get apis

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, routes

I have MERN application, where I serve `index.html` on all routes. But bellow that, I declare another apis for request.

```
router.post('/add-bin', newBin);
router.get('/recent-bins', recentBins);
router.get('/fetch-bin/:filename', fetchBin);
app.use(router);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')); // Front is built with react
});
```

In the development mode, where I was using proxy, everything was going fine, but when I deployed my web application on heroku, All the GET apis are overrode by that `app.get("*" ...)` part.

P.S I am quite new to Node and Express.

Answer (score -1):

First, in client run `npm run build` this will generate the `build` folder, where will be your frontend production code. In your backend you should serve that folder (this usually will be done in your index.js).

```
app.use(express.static('path/to/client/build')) 
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')); // Front is built with react
});
```

After that, you'll need to add some commands (in your package.json) to prepare the client for the deploy.

```
"scripts": { 
    "build": "cd path/to/client && npm run build",
    //we'll need to install client packages
    "i-client-packages": "cd client && npm install",
    //heroku will execute this command post-build
    //this will be needed to run the previous commands
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run i-client-packages && npm run build"
    //...the other commands (start, test, etc...)
}
```

More info about how to deploy a MERN app to heroku [here](https://kaushalvivek.github.io/2020-06-28-mern-heroku-deployment/).

Comment: I asked absolutely different thing.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood